# ERROR: can not execute INSERT in an only read transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am doing an INSERT query to my DB, but I have the error that is described in the title (translated from Spanish).

I think that the problem is that PostgresSQL "understands" that is another user who is doing the query, and has no grants to write, but in the application.properties I am using the connection parametres that I use to connect in the database manager system.

If I execute the same query directly in postgresql it works. Why doesn´t it work when I do the query from the DAO?

DAO:

```
@Override
    public Object register(String name, String surname, String email, String password) {
    StringBuilder queryStB = new StringBuilder();

    queryStB.append("INSERT INTO Users (user_name,surname,email,user_password,app_admin)"
            + " VALUES (:user_name,:surname,:email,:user_password,:app_admin ) ");



    String queryString = queryStB.toString();

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);

    query.setParameter("user_name",name);
    query.setParameter("surname",surname);
    query.setParameter("email",email);
    query.setParameter("user_password",password);
    query.setParameter("app_admin",false);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

APPLICATION.PROPERTIES

```
server.port=8081
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password=******

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Comment: Are you connected to a hot standby database?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate EntityManager's createNamedQuery method only supports select queries. This is what the error message indicates.

I also checked and haven't seen any examples of people using the method for insert or update queries.